# Is there a semi-decidable statement equivalent to the Collatz-conjecture?

Tags: reference-request, open-problem, decidability

We cannot rule out that the Collatz-conjecture cannot be proven. But we also cannot rule out that it is false and we cannot prove this in the case the sequence diverges for some start-number.

> Is there a provable semi-decidable statement equivalent to the Collatz-conjecture ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is at present no $\Sigma^0_1$ (= provably true if true) or $\Pi^0_1$ (= provably false if false) sentence which is known to be equivalent$^1$ to the Collatz conjecture.

Note that checking whether a sentence is $\Sigma^0_1$, or $\Pi^0_1$, is decidable: [it's a purely *syntactic* property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy). The issue is the "equivalent" bit.

---

$^1$Equivalence of sentences isn't a meaningful notion without specifying a "base theory:" two sentences $p,q$ are equivalent *over $T$* if $T$ proves $p\leftrightarrow q$. The naive "theory-free" definition of equivalence - "$p$ is equivalent to $q$ if $p\leftrightarrow q$ is true" - leads to all true statements being equivalent and all false statements being equivalent. When we replace "true" with "provable," we get something more interesting, but then we have to specify a theory: provable *in what system*?

I haven't specified a base theory above. However, there is no reasonable $T$ over which the Collatz conjecture is known to be equivalent to a $\Sigma^0_1$ or $\Pi^0_1$ sentence. If you like, take $T$ to be ZFC.

Comment: I've deleted the comment and expanded into a question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3822343/334732